# FME Form - Measure FME transformers execution time in the FME workbench

Tags: fme-form

One of my FME workbenches takes too long time for processing data. I am trying to optimize it. Therefore, looking for the stage where data being processed the longest.

Is there a way to measure processing time of each transformer, other than reading logs line by line?

Comment: The logger transform will do this, and you can set the level of debugging in the options. Can you also give your version of FME to narrow this down. https://community.safe.com/s/article/the-badnews-function-returns-a-whole-load-of-error

Comment: Thank you. Version is 2020.2

Comment: FME 2023.1 was just released they have improved a number of transformers and readers.

Answer (score 1):

When I have to do something like this I parse the logfile tot Excel, calculate time diff between rows and work from there.